# Android container transform image retention after exit app

Tags: android, android-animation

I am doing a minimal prototype of animating view from one activity (`MainActivity`) to another (`NextActivity`) via [container transform](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion#container-transform).

It works however when I exit the app, the transformed view stays for a while on launcher, which is unintended.

I guess it is probably an SDK bug, but do let me know if there is any workaround available, or did I missed out anything.

**Device: OnePlus 5T**

[image: Demo]

**MainActivity#onCreate**

```
window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)
    setExitSharedElementCallback(MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback())
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val icon: View = findViewById(R.id.icon)
    icon.postDelayed({
        val intent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java)
        val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            this,
            icon,
            "splash"
        )
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
        finish()
    }, 300)
```

**NextActivity#onCreate**

```
window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)
    setEnterSharedElementCallback(MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback())
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next)
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:background="@color/teal_200"
    android:transitionName="splash" />
```

**activity_next.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end|top"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    android:transitionName="splash" />
</FrameLayout>
```